Blood and Water
In Revelation 16:12 the “water” of the Euphrates River is dried up, but in Revelation 16:4 all of the “water” in the rivers was turned to “blood”. How do you reconcile these two verses?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

There is no obvious conflict between the two verses.

One explanation could be that just  before drying out completely a reddish looking bottom sediment gets visible.

Revelation is a series of symbolic scenes, in which not everything we see is meant to be understood literally, and we need not expect consistency between different images. Not that there is necessarily any inconsistency between the general statement of v4 and the locally changed situation of v12.
But I suggest the real difference here is that the v4 image is about the state of the waters, and the v12 image is not.
If we compare v12 with Isaiah ch11 vv15-16, the common factor is "ease of transit". The Isaiah passage is about how easily the "remnant of his people" will be able to escape from Assyria and Egypt.  v12 is about how easily the kings of the east will be able to reach and attack God's people in Israel.

+1... I'd add that the text itself explicitly states that these waters are symbolic in the next chapter when it says: Revelation 17:15
, “The waters that you saw, where the whore is seated, are peoples and multitudes and nations and languages."

Agreed - this is a series of symbols/metaphors whose literal meaning cannot be pressed.

Apparently the Euphrates River is already drying up, primarily due to the proliferation of dams together with a severe drought: https://www.discovermagazine.com/planet-earth/is-the-euphrates-river-drying-up. I'd imagine such an event will likely lead to a exegetical crisis by 2040 if the estimate by a hydrologist comes true.

@Dieter Indeed, the event is already being brought up in online popular exegesis. Along with the always-imminent destruction of Damascus.
